# .app file not working in other MAC system

Tags: osx-yosemite, .app, libmysql

I have created a MAC application with libraries 'libmysqlclient.a' and 'libmysqlclient.18.dylib' with Objective-C language in Xcode 6.3.1 in OSX Yosemite 10.10.3. Its working fine when running through Xcode. And I also archived the .app file to install the app in my MAC, its also working fine. But when i tried to install it in another mac, app crashed and shows the message

"dyld: Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib   Referenced from: /Users/developer/Documents/UntitledFolder/UserName/SampleApp.app/Contents/MacOS/SampleApp   Reason: image not found".

From this message i understand that the particular MAC does not have “libmysqlclient.18.dylib”. So, here my question is "Is it mandatory that each MAC should have the library to install and run the application?". Can anyone give me the solution for this with detailed format of creating the .app file and installing it in other MAC systems.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have included both a static (.a) and a dynamic (.dylib) library with your app. that do the same thing.  A static library compiles into your program, making it larger.  A dynamic library ships with your app. or is already install on your target system.  If you ship it with your app., it should be in the Frameworks folder of your app. (you create this folder in Build Phases, Copy File).  Use install_name_tool -id to set the library install name to @executable_path\..\Frameworks and also in Build Settings, set Runpath Search Paths to the same.